# Does MySQL support "IF EXISTS"?

Tags: mysql, syntax, if-statement, exists

I think I have a conflict between my knowledge on SQL Server and MySQL.
When I run this query, I get an error always from MySQL:

```
If EXISTS (select * from tbl_admin) THEN
    select 'OK';
END IF;
```

The error message is:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if EXISTS (select * from tbl_admin) then select '1'
>   -- select '1' WHERE EXISTS ' at line 1

Please help me and tell me am I wrong in writing this query? What's wrong?
I want to do something if I have something in `tbl_admin` table.

Comment: The error message does not correspond to your posted code. As far as I can tell, `IF EXISTS` is not valid MySQL syntax, though it exists in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 'ok'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
where table_name = 'tbl_admin'
```

### edit

To check if a table contains data you can do this:

```
SELECT 'OK' FROM dual
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_admin);
```

Comment: this will return ok if the table is present, but the user wants if a row is present in that table

Comment: juergen d, may you give me a code using IF EXISTS ? It's important to me to know its right syntax.

Comment: You can't use `if exists` in MySQL. You can only use `where exists(select ...)` in a `where` clause.

Comment: so `SELECT 'OK' WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tbl_admin);` must execute with no error, right ?

Comment: you need a `from` clause: `SELECT 'OK' from dual WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tbl_admin);`

Comment: or just `SELECT count(*) from tbl_admin`. it will return the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you know there is a table, you just need an info if there are any rows?
In that case I think this solves your problem:

```
SELECT 
    'OK'
FROM
    Korisnik
WHERE
    EXISTS( SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            Korisnik)
LIMIT 1;
```

You can use `IF EXISTS` to check for stored procedure or trigger existence. In SELECT queries you can use `WHERE EXISTS` or `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
if ( (select count(*) from tbl_admin) > 0) then
    ...
```

This counts all the rows in the table. If no rows are there, it will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
select if(count(*), 'OK', '') as result from table_name where 1
```

This will print "OK" if there are records present, else nothing will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when count(*) > 0 then 'OK' else 'Empty' end from tbl_admin;
```

OR

```
select 'OK' from tbl_admin having count(*) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check table existence then use this

```
 select 'Message' from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables where table_name = 'tbl_admin'
```

because all information is stored here.EXISTS also works fine in mysql.

Answer (score -2):

Use the normal select query..

```
Select 'OK' from table
```